# Lighten an area using css

Tags: html, css

http://asifslab.com
I want to lighten the area behind and near the logo on which the logo is located. The purpose for this is because the border of the logo is mixed with the background. Please help

Comment: try to set opacity of background but i don't think its works either because both color are same

Comment: use box shadow to do it if you want. don't give the x and y offsets but just give a blur with distance and a colour that you want to use to lighten the area.

Answer (score 2):

To softly lighten up the area behing the logo you can use a combination of an rgba background, rounded borders and a light shadow on the image:

```
.head > img {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Don't forget to add vendor-prefixes to support all browsers...

Comment: I want to make it circular, oval kind of

Comment: Try increasing the [`border-radius`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#corners) or play with the radius of the individual corners. Add a `padding` to the image to increase the area to lighten up. And please at least try to find a solution on your own first, for your own benefit. http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Actually none of you have given me what I wanted it like this http://s23.postimage.org/sq8ze5h57/Capture.png

Answer (score 0):

You can add a background with rgba property to give a fake light background.

Try this

```
#logo {
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
   /* Then other css */
}
```

In your case, modify your .head to this

```
.head {
  padding-left: 5%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "border" as you put it is margin on the `body`. To remove this, simply:

```
body { margin:0; }
```

What you can do is give the `.head` divider an opaque background:

```
.head { background:rgba(255,255,255,0.3); }
```

This **isn't** supported on older browsers, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

1. convert to PNG and make the original image 0.2 opacity
2. (better) have a `<div>` that is position: absolute inside `body` and the same height as `body`, then apply the `background image` and `opacity: 0.2; filter: alpha(opacity=20);`

Answer (score 0):

Try [CSS3 please](http://css3please.com)

```
.box_shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #fff; /* Android 2.3+, iOS 4.0.2-4.2, Safari 3-4 */
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #fff; /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 4+, IE 9+, iOS 5+, Opera 10.50+ */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by 2 ways 
1 `text-shadow` but you are using image so you have to do this in photoshop in `layer style > drop shadow` and select light color 
   you can do this in this also but it covers in rectangular form not behind your logo text

and

2 is to use background that also have the same effect in rectangular form 
    use `background:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);`
    last 0.6 is opacity adjust this to darken or ligten the color